# Airflow db init ERROR - Failed to add operation for GET /api/v1/connections

Tags: centos, airflow, centos8

I am trying to install Airflow 2.0.1 with ansible on CentOS8 machine. Python version 3.8.1. I made pip 20.2.4 as suggested in Airflow docs.

I am using postgresql and `airflow db check` is successful. But the db init task gives the following error. I tried `airflow  db init` manually but the result was the same:

```
ERROR - Failed to add operation for GET /api/v1/connections
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 209, in add_paths
    self.add_operation(path, method)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 162, in add_operation
    operation = make_operation(
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/operations/__init__.py", line 8, in make_operation
    return spec.operation_cls.from_spec(spec, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/operations/openapi.py", line 128, in from_spec
    return cls(
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/operations/openapi.py", line 75, in __init__
    super(OpenAPIOperation, self).__init__(
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/operations/abstract.py", line 96, in __init__
    self._resolution = resolver.resolve(self)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/resolver.py", line 40, in resolve
    return Resolution(self.resolve_function_from_operation_id(operation_id), operation_id)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/resolver.py", line 66, in resolve_function_from_operation_id
    raise ResolverError(str(e), sys.exc_info())
connexion.exceptions.ResolverError: <ResolverError: columns>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/airflow/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/db_command.py", line 31, in initdb
    db.initdb()
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 549, in initdb
    upgradedb()
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 684, in upgradedb
    command.upgrade(config, 'heads')
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 294, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 490, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 97, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 182, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 108, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 102, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 813, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 561, in run_migrations
    step.migration_fn(**kw)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/migrations/versions/2c6edca13270_resource_based_permissions.py", line 314, in upgrade
    remap_permissions()
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/migrations/versions/2c6edca13270_resource_based_permissions.py", line 289, in remap_permissions
    appbuilder = create_app(config={'FAB_UPDATE_PERMS': False}).appbuilder
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 120, in create_app
    init_api_connexion(flask_app)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/www/extensions/init_views.py", line 171, in init_api_connexion
    api_bp = connexion_app.add_api(
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/apps/flask_app.py", line 57, in add_api
    api = super(FlaskApp, self).add_api(specification, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/apps/abstract.py", line 144, in add_api
    api = self.api_cls(specification,
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 111, in __init__
    self.add_paths()
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 216, in add_paths
    self._handle_add_operation_error(path, method, err.exc_info)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 231, in _handle_add_operation_error
    raise value.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/resolver.py", line 61, in resolve_function_from_operation_id
    return self.function_resolver(operation_id)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/utils.py", line 111, in get_function_from_name
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/api_connexion/endpoints/connection_endpoint.py", line 26, in <module>
    from airflow.api_connexion.schemas.connection_schema import (
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/api_connexion/schemas/connection_schema.py", line 42, in <module>
    class ConnectionSchema(ConnectionCollectionItemSchema):  # pylint: disable=too-many-ancestors
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 121, in __new__
    klass._declared_fields = mcs.get_declared_fields(
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/sqlalchemy_schema.py", line 94, in get_declared_fields
    fields.update(mcs.get_auto_fields(fields, converter, opts, dict_cls))
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/sqlalchemy_schema.py", line 104, in get_auto_fields
    {
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/sqlalchemy_schema.py", line 105, in <dictcomp>
    field_name: field.create_field(
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/sqlalchemy_schema.py", line 28, in create_field
    return converter.field_for(model, column_name, **self.field_kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/convert.py", line 171, in field_for
    return self.property2field(prop, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/convert.py", line 146, in property2field
    field_class = field_class or self._get_field_class_for_property(prop)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/convert.py", line 210, in _get_field_class_for_property
    column = prop.columns[0]
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1220, in __getattr__
    return self._fallback_getattr(key)
  File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1194, in _fallback_getattr
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: columns
```

Comment: getting the same error. Was there a solution to this?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. Yes. I set the AIRFLOW_HOME and AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN environment before run db init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the `AIRFLOW_HOME` and `AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN` environment before run `airflow db init`.

Playbook version

```
environment:
    AIRFLOW_HOME: "{{ airflow_app_home }}"
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: "{{ airflow_database_conn }}"
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm having the same issue, temp fix was to use sqlalchemy < 1.4. Maybe that works for you.

Comment: apache-airflow 2.1.3  did not like SQLAlchemy 1.4.23. I missed this error during airflow install: `ERROR: flask-appbuilder 3.3.2 has requirement SQLAlchemy<1.4.0, but you'll have sqlalchemy 1.4.23 which is incompatible.` Replaced SQLAlchemy 1.4.23 with 1.3.24, problem solved.

Comment: @jscott Can you please explain , How to replace SQLAlchemy 1.4.23 with 1.3.24 ?

Comment: @Vinay Assuming you're using pip, `pip uninstall sqlalchemy` followed by `pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.24` should do it

Comment: For those interested in running airflow with sqlalchemy 1.4 here are the PRs/issues to monitor: [Airflow PR removing sqlalchemy 1.4 constraint](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/16630), [flask-appbuilder still requiring < 1.4](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/issues/1621).

Answer (score 2):

What Worked for me is setting AIRFLOW_HOME and AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN  and `pip install SQLAlchemy==1.3.24`

Answer (score 2):

For me and Airflow 2.3.1 upgrading `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` helped.

```
pip install -U marshmallow-sqlalchemy
```